# bootstrap pagination update current page only update server side .i want all page update so how to date pagination

Tags: bootstrap-4

i'm updated bootstrap table multi checkbox. clicked all selected.But update only current page.

```
function generateTest()
        {
            tableId = $('#test').DataTable({
                "bPaginate": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                "aoColumns": [
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null//put as many null values as your columns
                ]
            });
}
```

Comment: I only see a javascript datatables here, nothing jsf related

Comment: Okay,   I'm using multiple checkbox  p:selectBooleanCheckbox now i'm clicked all checkbox checked.Then i will updated p:commandButton action. but saved only current page list only update . another remaining page not clocked and update. so how can updated the process.

Comment: Sorry, I do not use bootrap, so no idea...